# "ORIENTDB_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly" while running OrientDB for first time

Tags: database, orientdb, nosql

I am trying to start OrientDB server but i get the following error "The ORIENTDB_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly This environment variable is needed to run this program." I have created the environment variable but the error still persists. Can someone help me out?

**UPDATE:**When I try to run the server.bat directly by double clicking it made the server active and I am able to browse it but when I try to create a new database it ask me the username and password,and when I enter the "root" as username and "hello"(the password I set when It asked me 1st time) it gives an authentication error.
Screenshot: http://prntscr.com/9f81i4
I have also tried looking into the server config file for the password.It has the same password.

Comment: Which version are you using?

Comment: I have just downloaded it from the website.Its community edition 2.1.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try to replace the Studio plugin (in the /plugins directory) with this?
https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/blob/2.1.x/server/plugins/studio-2.1.zip?raw=true

Answer (score 0):

Yes ,I faced the same problem. As you said your server.bat is running fine and active then their no issue with the ORIENTDB_HOME environment variable you need to just restart or shutdown the machine. OR you can directly set path from command prompt.